# How can i fix this annoying error ? "console.error there was a problem sending log messages to your development environment..."

Tags: react-native, expo

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2psy.jpg)

After i upgraded expo sdk from 35 to 36 i started to get this annoying error that keep showing after i navigate from page to page, this doesn't stop app from running, i can dismiss it and keep going, but it's very annoying it's keep showing everytime i navigate throught the app.
I need help fixing this error please... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this specific warning by disabling YellowBox .
To know more please visit [Disable the Yellow Box in React Native](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/5/Disable-the-Yellow-Box-in-React-Native)